# How to check which env activated in anaconda-mode

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I use [purcell/emacs.d](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d) configuration. When coding with python, I use following command to activate an env, with [anaconda-mode](https://github.com/pythonic-emacs/anaconda-mode).

```
M-x pythonic-activate RET /path/to/virtualenv RET
```

But nothing changes in the front window.

How to know which env is currently activated?